# I can't get a LinearLayout to appear below a scroll view

Tags: android

I want the buttons to appear under the scrollview but they don't show. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Task ID:"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTask_taskId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="929333" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Task Name:"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTask_taskName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Test Task Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date:"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTask_taskDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="15/01/2013" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Status:"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTask_taskStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Active" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type:"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTask_taskType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Standard" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLabel6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description:"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTask_taskDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here Long description goes here " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Reject" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFinish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Finish" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to tell give them a "layout_weight", so your childs ScrollView and LinearLayout know how much space they use.

try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
 android:weightSum="2" />
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    ...
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
```

...